# Simple XL release task is failing

Tags: groovy, xlrelease

I have a very simple task, a Groovy script, which takes a variable, and splits it into a list, then prints the list.  It does exactly this, then fails the task.  I don't understand why, because it literally runs through the script and then should exit successfully as far as I'm aware.  If I try to manually complete the task in the script, it hangs.

Here's the script:

```
def jira_tickets = releaseVariables['jira_Ticket_list'].split(',')
releaseVariables['jira_tickets'] = jira_tickets

println("Tickets: ${jira_tickets}")
```

I've tried it with this line added:

```
taskApi.transitionTask(task.id, 'Complete')
```

Which is what causes it to hang.  I've also tried to use error handling, and it doesn't have an error, the output is merely exactly what I want it to do.  Why is this failing the task at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the reason it was failing, but I switched to Python and it worked, so that is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use Async.

```
taskApi.transitionTask(task.id, 'Complete').async()
```

After printing the list of tickets and then start the task in the background. The script will then continue executing and will not hang.